# Create Text Field on Selection of Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple quote form that im having a few issues with, I'd like a text field to appear when specific fields are selected from the dropdown menu, my code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#hear").change(function(){       
             $("#quote").find(".field").remove(); 
             //or
               $('#quote').remove('.field');
          if( $(this).val()=="value5")
             {
        $("#quote").append("<input class='field' type='text' />");

             }
          });

});
</script>

<form id="quote" class="quote-form">
<input name="" class="text-field" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" />
<input name="" class="text-field" type="text" placeholder="Contact Number" />
<input name="" class="text-field" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail Address" />
<select id="hear" name="hear" class="select-field">
<option value="value1" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Where did you hear about us? (Please Select)</option>
  <option value="value2">Check-a-Trade</option>
  <option value="value3">MyBuilder</option>
  <option value="value4">Referred by a Friend (Please State)</option>
  <option value="value5">Other (Please State)</option>
</select>
<input name="" class="text-field" type="text" placeholder="Location" />
<textarea name="" cols="" rows="8" class="text-area" placeholder="Description of your Desired Works.."></textarea>
<input name="" type="submit" class="quote-form-button"/>


</form>
```

The code above should create a text field when "other" is selected, although i'm having a few issues, any help is appreciated, cheers!

Comment: I dont see any PHP code so I have removed that tag and added javascript and jquery

Comment: What issues are you having, SO is not a free debugging service where you just throw your code up for a free review. Specify what the issue is

Comment: That code snippet you pasted works. Try it here: https://jsbin.com/xalema/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Apologies, new to this, i commented on the post below with the issue. Oliver, thank you, although its still not achieving the same result on my end, live example at mwlandscapers.com/site .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention detailed error.However instead of removing a field I thing hiding should be a better option.Although that could vary based on your exact requirement.

In this example when you select "Other" then a textbox gets created with a supplied index.On some other selection text field gets hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$('#hear').change(function() {
var val = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
if (val == "Other") {
$("#quote").append('<input type="text" name="textbox' + index + '" id="textbox' + index + '" value="">');
} 
if(val == "some value"){
$('#your text field id').hide();
}).change();
});
```